# After running the cognos report the data is not being displayed

Tags: report, cognos

After running the cognos report the data is not being displayed .. checked the same queries in sql server the data is being retrived but not displayed in cognos report ...can someone help

Comment: How do you know you checked the correct SQL?  Where did you get the SQL for the queries?  Did you try running the queries (in Cognos), or only the report?

Comment: Any update, can you tell us a little more information.  What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions

- Try building a simple list and see if it shows results (to rule out your browser)
- Check the properties - make sure it wasn't something like box type = none
- Look for conflicting filters
- If you have a join, check if it is an inner join.  If so, does that cause an empty result set?  Try it with an outer join